# .NET3.5 installed automatically with InstallShield2009

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installshield-2009

how .NET3.5 installed automatically with InstallShield2009

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Here's a guide for .NET 2 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/installdotnet2.aspx - do you need 3.5 specifically?

Comment: BTW, if people take the time to answer your questions, don't forget to accept the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just select it as a prerequisite when you go through the quick setup screens (i.e. not the detailed screen - it can be done there also with the prerequisite editor but takes a few more clicks of the mouse).

You may have to [download the redistributable package](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q200284), i cannot recall if it ships with the 2009 version of the product or is a separate download. Once included as part of your MSI, it will be launched as a chained install when the user runs your one.

Comment: @jackStonre - your comment doesn't make any sense to me - what are you asking?  Are you asking how to include just the basic .Net 3.5 redistributable (i.e. not the full install) so that the client has to download it?